# If statement Runs single time and works however While statement runs infinitely and doesn't work

Tags: python

Here is a simple Binary RLE Function I am currently working on:

```
        x = 0

        while string[i] == '0':
            output.append('A')
        while string[i] == '1':
            output.append('B')
        output.append(x)
        leng -= x

    return(output)

print(rle("0011"))
```

After adding print statements after each line to check where the problem lies due to the lack of output when running this code it is evident that it is simply running forever instead of checking the next character and moving on. If the `whille string[i] == '0':` and the `while string[i] == '1':` are changed to `if string[i] == '0':` and `if string[i] == '1':` then the output is technically correct except it repastes the Character repeating itself in between one's essentially not doing it's job at all. I can't seem to find any alternative ways without using if or while statements to complete this task either.

Comment: what is the output you need?

Comment: @OsadhiVirochana for this example it would be A2B2 if the input was 00000 the output should be A5 with A representing 0's, B representing 1's and the following number representing how many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `count()`

```
def rle(s):
    a = 'A' + str(s.count('0')) if s.count('0') else ''
    b = 'B' + str(s.count('1')) if s.count('1') else ''
    return a + b

print(rle("0011"))
```

Comment: This works but are there any other methods that would work with repetitions like "0011001011" or larger binary strings?

Comment: @Nebula I don't know about that, but you can use  `numpy.count_nonzero` for counting.

Answer (score 0):

Using `groupby` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import groupby

def rle(string):
    string = string.replace('0','A').replace('1','B')
    return "".join([key+str(len(list(group))) for key, group in groupby(string)])


print(rle("0011"))
```

output:

```
A2B2
```

Comment: maybe string is not the best name in hindsight